# AIrflow - unable to access dag_run.conf in SubDag

Tags: airflow

I'm stuck at a point where I have to send trigger parameters to the SubDag from the parent dag.

How do I achieve this. I used the same code That I had used to access the trigger parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll want to share your code and any errors you may have received.